# Pool.map - Why doesn't the worker process crash earlier?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Say I do this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    raise OverflowError  # raised BEFORE the print
    print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test0.py", line 9, in <module>
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
  File "/Users/usualme/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
OverflowError
```

Ok the output makes sense. The exception is raised before the `print` statement, so there is no output. Now almost the same code, but I switched 2 lines:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    print x
    raise OverflowError  # raised AFTER the print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Out:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test0.py", line 9, in <module>
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
  File "/Users/usualme/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
OverflowError
```

I don't understand the output. I was expecting either the number 0 followed by the stack trace, or all 10 numbers and 10 stack traces. Why is it printing all numbers and only one stack trace? Why does the worker process wait the very end to crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a timing thing - The `worker` process doesn't care that an exception is raised in the function it's running, it just returns the exception to the parent and keeps chugging along with the next task. Here's the loop it's running (slightly simplified):

```
while maxtasks is None or (maxtasks and completed < maxtasks):
    try:
        task = get()  # Get task from parent
    except (EOFError, OSError):
        util.debug('worker got EOFError or OSError -- exiting')
        break

    if task is None:
        util.debug('worker got sentinel -- exiting')
        break

    job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    try:
        result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))  # Call the function pass from the parent
    except Exception as e:  # We end up in here if the worker raises an exception
        if wrap_exception:
            e = ExceptionWithTraceback(e, e.__traceback__)
        result = (False, e)  # The exception object is stored as the result

    put((job, i, result)) # Send result to parent process
```

So, even though the very first task raises an exception, it takes a little bit of time for the result to travel between the two processes, and for the parent process to actually pull the result out of the `Queue` and raise the `Exception`. In that window of time, the worker is able to execute all the remaining tasks. If you make the worker function slower, you'll see it executes fewer tasks:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def f(x):
    print x
    time.sleep(2)
    raise OverflowError 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output:

```
0
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 11, in <module>
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 626, in next
    raise value
OverflowError
```

You'd also only see some percentage of the results printed if you passed a larger iterable, since the worker wouldn't have enough time to get through all of them before the parent died.

You only see one exception actually get raised because from the parent's perspective, as soon as one task has failed, the entire `imap` call should be aborted. The parent pulls the results from all its child processes from a single `Queue` sequentially, so as soon as it sees the first exception, the `imap` call ends, so the results from the rest of the tasks get thrown away.